# Does hose bib affect Backflow Preventer/Pressure Vacuum Breaker?

Tags: plumbing, irrigation

I have a Pressure Vacuum Breaker (PVB) that I've installed that is 12" above the highest point of sprinklers, as recommended by install guides.

I'd like to add a hose bib downstream of the PVB. If I tap into the PVB, and the hose bib is 12" off the ground, do I need to raise the PVB 12 more inches?

On a related note, if I'm using one of those pop up sprinklers that pops up 8", do I need the PVB to be 12" above that when it's extended? Or just when it's not in use?

Comment: Did the guide say 12” or **at least** 12”? Because if you mounted it higher none of these questions would need asking.

Comment: @Ecnerwal thanks, done.

Comment: @SolarMike at least. But my line of questioning is do I need to do the additional work to move the PVB higher or not? I don't want to do unnecessary work.